# quantize result has too many digits for current context

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Im trying to save the operation result in my admin.py and i have this error:

> quantize result has too many digits for current context

```
....
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

    usuario_libra   = obj.consignee.membresia.libra
    valores         = Valores.objects.get(pk=1)
    vtasa           = valores.tasa
    vaduana         = valores.aduana
    vgestion        = valores.gestion
    vfee            = valores.fee
    vcombustible    = valores.combustible

    trans_aereo     = obj.peso * usuario_libra * vtasa
    aduana          = (obj.peso * vaduana )*vtasa
    fee_airpot      = (obj.peso * vfee)*vtasa
    combustible     = (obj.peso * vcombustible)*vtasa
    itbis           = (trans_aereo+vgestion)*Decimal(0.16)
    total           = trans_aereo + vgestion + aduana + fee_airpot + combustible + itbis

    if not obj.id:
        obj.total = total
        ...
```

What this mean?, all my model fields are Decimal
Any help please

Thank you

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051575/django-combine-models-decimalfield-with-forms-error-quantize-result-has-too) help?

Comment: @okm i tried and dont help :(

Answer (score 26):

I was able to solve this problem by increasing the the 'max_digits' field option.

```
class Myclass(models.Model):
  my_field = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

Be sure to make it large enough to fit the longest number you wish to save.

If that does not work may also need to set the precision larger by:

```
from decimal import getcontext
  ...
  getcontext().prec = 11
```

See the python decimal documentation for full context parameters.

Comment: Note, this isn't ideal since it changes the context everywhere, which might break other code that uses more than 11 digits.

Comment: After it worked it decrease the digit count as before and it worked too